# Captcha UIImage to NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uiimage, web-scraping

This is my code:

```
[self.webScraper scrape:@"https://fordonsfraga.transportstyrelsen.se/fragapaannatfordon.aspx"
               selector:@"//*[@id=\"frmFordonsFraga\"]/table[3]/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/img"
                handler:^(NSArray *elements, NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"Load %lu elements.", (unsigned long)elements.count);

                    for (NSDictionary* img in elements) {
                        NSString* url = [[img objectForKey:@"attributes"] objectForKey:@"src"];
                        NSLog(@"%@",url);
                        NSString* imgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://fordonsfraga.transportstyrelsen.se/%@", url];
                        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl]];
                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        _logga.image =image;
                        NSUInteger len = [data length];
                        NSFC
                        NSString * string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[data base64Encoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                        NSLog(@"%@", string);


                    }
                }];
```

Basically it downloads the captcha image and I wanna turn that data into a string to answer the captcha? The image displays correctly.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: This is exactly what the CAPTCHA is trying to **prevent**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract string from image by using `OCR` (optical character recognition). You can use OCR libraries (like `tesseract`or `leptonica`).check [Link](https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios-lib), you can get samples.

Answer (score 1):

You should do some image processing for that and it's not that easy. Check OpenCv - it's a successful open-source library.
http://opencv.org